# Count individual records in SQL database

Tags: count, records, mariadb

I have a medium sized mariadb with 385 tables in it and I want to know how many data points/records there are in the entire database. I looked into COUNT but that does not seem to be what I want, is there a summary screen or something I can do to let me know?

Thanks.

Comment: Most SQL client tools offer such a feature. You need to check your SQL client, there is nothing built into the DBMS.

Comment: I have HeidiSQL but it looks like you only can see row counts, i need rows + columns, or amount of individual cells/records.

Answer (score 0):

See the `information_schema` database; `TABLES` and `COLUMNS` tables.